# Recover file history in SVN

Tags: svn, move

When I was trying to move a file which is under SVN source code, I cut it in current directory (A) and then pasted it to another directory (B).  Now history of this file is lost. Is there anything I can do to recover file history?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just revert the commit and do a proper `svn move`

Comment: @echo The history will just continue appending to the restored history before the move.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tortoise SVN, when committing the file, you can select "Repair Move". In the commit dialog, select the "missing" file and the "unversioned" file, right click, and select "Repair Move".

Comment: Well, I think it helps when I am going to make a mistake but not after I made the mistake already...